# Problema, quiero crear un boton con una accion en laravel

Tags: laravel, botón, crud

estoy haciendo un CRUD en laravel, y deseo añadir un botón para habilitar e inhabilitar usuarios, ya tengo ese campo creado en la base de datos, y logre que de acuerdo a  dicho estado aparezca un botón para habilitar/inhabilitar, pero ese botón no tiene ninguna acción y no se como hacer que funcione. Alguna sugerencia?.

```
                          @if($user->activo())
                          <form action="{{ route('users.update', $user) }}" method="POST">
                          @method('PUT')
                          @csrf
                          <input type="submit"
                          value="Inhabilitar"
                          onclick="$user->enable_at('1')">
                          </form>

                          @else
                          <form action="{{ route('users.update', $user) }}" method="POST">
                          @method('PUT')
                          @csrf
                          <input type="submit"
                          value="Habilitar"
                          onclick="$user->enable_at('0')">
                          </form>
                          @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que estás mezclando código Javascript con código PHP. Cuando pones:

```
onclick="$user->enable_at('1')"
```

dentro del onclick se espera que pongas código Javascript, y tú pones código PHP. Deberías crear una función en javascript que utilizara alguna biblioteca que pueda hacer llamadas asincrónicas a otras páginas. Por ejemplo, la librería axios ya viene configurada por defecto en Laravel, por lo que quizá sería la más sencilla de utilizar para hacer un post a algún controlador y en dicho controlador actualizar el campo del usuario. En cualquier caso, podrías usar cualquier otra librería a tu elección, o hacerlo directamente en javascript sin librerías.

En PHP:

```
 onclick="actualizarUsuario({{ $user->id }})"
```

En JS:

```
function actualizarUsuario(id) { axios('/usuario/'+id+'/edit').then()  ... etc ... }
```

Si esto te parece complicado, puedes utilizar [Laravel Livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com), que básicamente intenta simplificar este tipo de procesos en componentes sencillos como el botón que indicas.

Comment: Gracias @BetaM , actualizado!